# how to loop through some ASP.NET labels to set their attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

How do I do this in a loop.

```
protected void ddlTool_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    lblTool1.Visible = false;
    txtTool1.Visible = false;
    lblTool2.Visible = false;
    txtTool2.Visible = false;
    lblTool3.Visible = false;
    txtTool3.Visible = false;
    lblTool4.Visible = false;
    txtTool4.Visible = false;
    lblTool5.Visible = false;


    if (ddlTool.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        lblTool1.Visible = true;
        txtTool1.Visible = true;
    }
    if (ddlTool.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        lblTool1.Visible = true;
        txtTool1.Visible = true;
        lblTool2.Visible = true;
        txtTool2.Visible = true;
    }
    if (ddlTool.SelectedValue == "3")
    {
        lblTool1.Visible = true;
        txtTool1.Visible = true;
        lblTool2.Visible = true;
        txtTool2.Visible = true;
        lblTool3.Visible = true;
        txtTool3.Visible = true;
    }
    if (ddlTool.SelectedValue == "4")
    {
        lblTool1.Visible = true;
        txtTool1.Visible = true;
        lblTool2.Visible = true;
        txtTool2.Visible = true;
        lblTool3.Visible = true;
        txtTool3.Visible = true;
        lblTool4.Visible = true;
        txtTool4.Visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of having a separate variable for each textbox and label, have a collection of them - whether that's a `List<T>` or an array or whatever.

Then you can do:

```
// Potentially use int.TryParse here instead
int visibleLabels = int.Parse(ddlTool.SelectedValue);
for (int i = 0; i < labels.Count; i++)
{
    labels[i].Visible = (i < visibleLabels);
    textBoxes[i].Visible = (i < visibleLabels);
}
```

(Alternatively use two loops, one to set some Visible properties to true, and one to set some to false.)

Comment: Since it's not obvious from the original description whether this is about Windows Forms or ASP.NET, I'll explain for both: make sure you initialize the array only once the controls are created (on Windows Forms, it's after the call to InitializeComponent(); on ASP.NET; it's after FrameworkInitialize(), so usually in the Load event). A better solution would be to use properties to initialize the arrays on first access only, potentially using .NET 4' new Lazy<T> class if you can.

Comment: Since control arrays aren't natively supported I thought this article about Creating Control Arrays in .NET would be a useful supplement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can access a control by its name using

```
container.Controls["nameofcontrol"]
```

So technically, you could use this to lookup your control

(Untested code)

```
for(int index = 1; index <= Convert.ToInt32(ddlTool.SelectedValue); index++)
{
    this.Controls["lblTool" + index.ToString()].Visible = true;
    this.Controls["txtTool" + index.ToString()].Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `UserControl` for each set of connected controls and then enable/disable the `UserControl` instead of all the component controls.  This is classic, basic modularization of your user interface.

Note that this will still require a little "redundant" code because you're working with an unusual UI paradigm by enabling up-to the ddlTool's selected value of your control.  E.g., create your user control that contains a single `Label` and `TextBox`.  Call it `LabeledTextBox` or something similar.  Then you'd create a collection of your labeled text boxes and enable them up to `int.Parse(ddlTool.SelectedValue) - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    int index = (int)ctrl.Name.Substring(ctrl.Name.Length - 1);
    int maxIndex = (int)ddlTool.SelectedValue;
    ctrl.Visible = (index <= maxIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with no error checking, but should match your code functionality.

```
protected void ddlTool_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  int selectedValue = int.Parse(ddlTool.SelectedValue.ToString());
  for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
  {
    bool state = i <= selectedValue;
    this.Controls["lblTool" + i.ToString()].Visible = state;
    this.Controls["txtTool" + i.ToString()].Visible = state;
  }
}
```